# I have this error: Couldn't fetch mysqli, with no database errors

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I am posting a form to insert values into a database using mysqli, I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: mysqli::real_escape_string() [mysqli.real-escape-string]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/richa161/public_html/chat/chat.class.php
```

I have tried wrapping it in an if statement to check for errors coming back from the DB but there are none. Here is my code:

```
require_once('config.php');

class Chat {

private $mysqli;

//open database connection
function __construct(){

    $this->mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DATABASE);

    if($this->mysqli->connect_error){

        die('error');

    } else {

        die('ok');

    }

}

//insert message to database
public function postMessage($username, $message){

    if ($this->mysqli->connect_error) {

        die('Connect Error: ' . $this->mysqli->connect_error);

    } else {

        //make data safe for database
        $username = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($username);
        $message = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($message);

        //build query
        $query = "INSERT INTO chat (post_date, username, message) VALUES(NOW(),'".$username."','".$message."')";

        //execute query and store in $result
        $result = $this->mysqli->query($query);

        echo $query;

    }
}

//close database connection
function __destruct(){

    $this->mysqli->close();

}

}
```

I am grabbing the form data using jQuery and sending it to another file which then uses the classes to call the function required. I do not think the problem is in these files however.. If you think I need to post them I will. Quite sure the error is in the above however.

Connection details are 100% correct..

The jQuery posts values username and message to this page which then calls the class:

```
require_once('chat.class.php');

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['chat'])){
    $_SESSION['chat'] = new chat();
}

$chat = $_SESSION['chat']; 

$username = $_POST['username'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//run function
$chat->postMessage($username, $message);
```

Starting to think it is the way in which I am posting to my file ajaxRouter.php which is above this text.

index.php contents:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#chatForm").submit(function(e){

e.preventDefault();

var username = $("input[name='username']").val();
var message = $("input[name='message']").val();

charCount = username.length;

if(!/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(username) && charCount > 2) {

    $.ajax({

        url: 'ajaxRouter.php',

        type: 'post',

        data: { 'username' : username, 'message' : message },

        success:function(result){

            console.log(result);

        }

    });

} else {

    alert("Username must be more than 2 charcters, no special charcters allowed");

}

});
</script>
```

Comment: You should check for errors against your INSERT. This `".$username.",".$message."` should throw you an error, since we're most likely dealing with strings and not `int`s.

Comment: Thanks, good spot I have edited the code to add quotes, however I still have the same error..

Comment: You *REALLY* should look into prepared statements. And store it in a new private property of your class. This will improve performance, maintainability and safety. Also, it will be easier to detect this kind of error and easier to program it.

Comment: Thanks I have looked at PDO but haven't transitioned into it yet..

Comment: @user1329580 You can use prepared statements in mysqli as well, check the manual.

Answer (score 2):

You are not constructing a `mysqli` object, the class `mysqli_connect` does not exist.

You need to change your constructor to:

```
function __construct(){
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DATABASE);
                        ^^^^^^ You need to construct a `mysqli` object
}
```

This is also wrong:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO chat (post_date, username, message) VALUES(NOW(),".$username.",".$message.")";
```

Assuming that `$username` and `$message` are strings, you need to quote them:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO chat (post_date, username, message)
            VALUES(NOW(),'{$username}','{$message}')";
                         ^           ^ ^          ^ here
```

**Edit:** You don't have any error handling in your constructor. To see if all mysqli calls execute without problems, you can setup mysqli to throw exceptions when something goes wrong so that you don't have to check manually on each call. To do that, add this to the top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

**Edit 2:** You cannot persist your database connection in your session like that. You need to start a new database connection every time the script is started. The most logical solution would be to separate the database operation from the `chat` class and instantiate that always.

Comment: OP edited the question with the quotes for the strings. But this makes a lot of sense ;-)

Comment: I have changed it to construct the object now, still same error

Comment: @jeroen I'm wondering if `$this->mysqli` is conflicting with the already built-in `mysqli` class?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, it is just a variable, they even do the same in the manual (well, kind of...): http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: They're doing `$this->db` and not `$this->mysqli` but I see what you're saying @jeroen

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, I just noticed. But the idea is the same :-)

Comment: I'm now wondering **how** the OP is using the `Chat` class as well as the function. This one's too unclear at this point. We'd have to practically setup a DB just for it to test it and the usage, which I'm not up to doing.

Comment: I enabled error display but still the same errors.. :S

Comment: @user1329580 See my latest edit, you don't have a database connection as a database connection does not persist in a session.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Turns out you were right, it's the *how* that did it :-)

Comment: @jeroen Thanks for the update my friend, *cheers* and enjoy that wonderful coffee of yours ;-)

Comment: The database connection doesn't exist because my constructor is getting completely ignored... :S, I have added die('here'); inside it and it does nothing.

Comment: @user1329580 That's because the session variable is set, so a new object is not generated and the constructor is never run. I don't think you should use a session variable for your `$chat` object, just generate a new one when the script starts.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to check is your DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DATABASE constants.
This error could happen when some of these don't have appropriate values.

Also make sure you quote your values as Fred -ii- pointed:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO chat (post_date, username, message) VALUES(NOW(),'".$username."','".$message."')";
```

**EDIT:**

This is from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

> The cryptic "Couldn't fetch mysqli" error message can mean any number
>   of things, including:
>
> 1. You're trying to use a database object that you've already closed. Reopen your database connection,
>      or find the call to  mysqli_close($db);  or  $db->close();
>      and remove it.
> 2. Your MySQLi object has been serialized and unserialized for some reason. Define a wakeup function to re-create your database
>      connection. http://php.net/__wakeup
> 3. Something besides you closed your mysqli connection (in particular, see http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33772)
> 4. You mixed OOP and functional calls to the database object. (So, you have  $db->query() in the same program as 
>      mysqli_query($db)).

Comment: I have tried connecting using the same config file outside of this project a few minutes ago and it connected OK..

Answer (score 0):

In postMessage(...) you check $this->mysqli->error, which isn't necessarily a connection error (what else is happening between the time the constructor is called and this function is called?). Try checking $this->mysqli->connect_error in __construct and if the connection failed, set $this->mysqli to null. Then you can then check whether or not $this->mysqli is instantiated before you try to use it in other places.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Nothing else happens between that time. I post values to the page which initializes the class and calls the method then the constructor is run and then the method. It is like the constructor is being ignored however as the edit to the constructor above in my original post does nothing, the page should die and print ok or fail either way... However it does none.. :S

Comment: Is the constructor dying with 'ok'?

Comment: No, I think I am going to try using PDO instead as it is better practice and there are no requirements for mysqli in the project anyway, thanks for your help! Guys!

Comment: If your constructor isn't getting called then PDO won't help, unless you move database initialization out of the constructor. This may be a typo, but you have "new chat()", can you try calling "new Chat()" instead (capitalized)?

Comment: changed it, no changes, the constructor definitely is not getting called, I have simply added die('here'); and it is ignored...

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. The problem occured because I have included two php files ; one for the database connection and another for users' authentication. The users' authentication file itself has the database connection file included. In effect two connections in one php file